# Creating sub-array of linearized 2d-array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am sure the solution is simpler than I think, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around it.

I am working with linearized (one-dimensional) arrays that contain 2d or 3d data. Specifically I work with NativeArrays in a Unity DOTS environment, but I'm sure there is a generic solution for this.

Here is my usecase in pseudo-code:

```
origin[] = {
  3, 4, 5,
  9, 8, 7,
  2, 1, 6
}

originSize = (3, 3)
```

Now I want to create a sub-array of position (1, 1) with size (2, 2) of this array.
I would expect to get

```
subarray[] = {
  8, 7,
  1, 6
}
```

My current code looks like this:

```
for loop over subarray with index...

int x = index % subSize.x;
int y = index / subSize.x;
int tileX = x + subPos.x * subSize.x;
int tileY = y + subPos.y * subSize.y;
int originIndex = tileX + tileY * originSize.x
subArray[index] = originArray[inputIndex];
```

This not only runs into out of bounds issues with some inputs, it is also quite slow (it's in a performance-critical part of code). I was hoping for a memcopy alternative, but as the data is fragmented in the array, my only idea is to go row by row, which seems not really fast either.

I tried to find general solutions for extracting sub-arrays, but could not find any solutions that do not use multi-dimensional or jagged arrays. It's important that the solution works with linear arrays and is fast.

Thank you!

Comment: `index / subSize.x;` would always be 0 due to `int` division wouldn't it?

Comment: Not if index is higher than `subSize.x` (the width). Index calculation like this is pretty normal for linearized 2d arrays. index is between 0 and `subSize.x  * subSize.y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should do it

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static T[] GetSubArray<T>( this T[] origin, int originDimensionsX, int originDimensionsY, int startPositionX, int startPositionY, int targetDimensionsX, int targetDimensionsY)
    {
        // First of all some checks
        if(origin == null) return null;
        if(origin.Length == 0) return new T[0];
        if(originDimensionsX < 0 || originDimensionsY < 0 || originDimensionsX * originDimensionsY != origin.Length) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Given dimensions {originDimensionsX},{originDimensionsY} do not match the given array length {origin.Length}!");
        if(startPositionX < 0 || startPositionX > originDimensionsX - 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Given startPosition {startPositionX} is outside of the origin dimensions {originDimensionsX}!");
        if(startPositionY < 0 || startPositionY > originDimensionsY - 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Given startPosition {startPositionY} is outside of the origin dimensions {originDimensionsY}!");
        if(targetDimensionsX < 0 || targetDimensionsY < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("TargetDimensions may not be negative!");
        if(startPositionX + targetDimensionsX > originDimensionsX || startPositionY + targetDimensionsY > originDimensionsY) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ($"Given TargetDimensions {targetDimensionsX},{targetDimensionsY} starting at {startPositionX},{startPositionY} does not fit into originDimensions {originDimensionsX},{originDimensionsY}!");

        var output = new T[targetDimensionsX * targetDimensionsY];

        var subIndex = 0;
        for(var y = startPositionY; y < startPositionY + targetDimensionsY; y++)
        {
            for(var x = startPositionX; x < startPositionX + targetDimensionsX; x++)
            {
                output[subIndex++] = origin[x + y * originDimensionsX];
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Example

```
var origin = new []
{ 
    0, 1, 2, 
    3, 4, 5, 
    6, 7, 8
};  

var subArray = origin.GetSubArray(3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2);

Debug.Log(string.Join(",", subArray));
```

would be

```
4, 5, 7, 8
```

---

Since for the **X dimension** we always copy **consecutive** values for large arrays it might be more efficient instead of the inner `for` loop to use

**[`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.copy)**

```
public static T[] GetSubArray(this int[] origin, int originDimensionsX, int originDimensionsY, int startPositionX, int startPositionY, int targetDimensionsX, int targetDimensionsY)
    {
        // First of all some checks
        if(origin == null) return null;
        if(origin.Length == 0) return new T[0];
        if(originDimensionsX < 0 || originDimensionsY < 0 || originDimensionsX * originDimensionsY != origin.Length) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Given dimensions {originDimensionsX},{originDimensionsY} do not match the given array length {origin.Length}!");
        if(startPositionX < 0 || startPositionX > originDimensionsX - 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Given startPosition {startPositionX} is outside of the origin dimensions {originDimensionsX}!");
        if(startPositionY < 0 || startPositionY > originDimensionsY - 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Given startPosition {startPositionY} is outside of the origin dimensions {originDimensionsY}!");
        if(targetDimensionsX < 0 || targetDimensionsY < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("TargetDimensions may not be negative!");
        if(startPositionX + targetDimensionsX > originDimensionsX || startPositionY + targetDimensionsY > originDimensionsY) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ($"Given TargetDimensions {targetDimensionsX},{targetDimensionsY} starting at {startPositionX},{startPositionY} does not fit into originDimensions {originDimensionsX},{originDimensionsY}!");

        var output = new T[targetDimensionsX * targetDimensionsY];

        var subIndex = 0;
        for(var y = startPositionY; y < startPositionY + targetDimensionsY; y++)
        {
            Array.Copy(origin, startPositionX + y * originDimensionsX, output, subIndex, targetDimensionsX);
            subIndex += targetDimensionsX;
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

---

Or you could also go down to the byte level and directly use **[`Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy)** (assuming int or other const size base type array now - not generic, you need to know the constant byte size of your type!)

```
const int SIZEOF_INT = sizeof(int);

public static int[] GetSubArray(this int[] origin, int originDimensionsX, int originDimensionsY, int startPositionX, int startPositionY, int targetDimensionsX, int targetDimensionsY)
    {
        // First of all some checks
        if(origin == null) return null;
        if(origin.Length == 0) return new T[0];
        if(originDimensionsX < 0 || originDimensionsY < 0 || originDimensionsX * originDimensionsY != origin.Length) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Given dimensions {originDimensionsX},{originDimensionsY} do not match the given array length {origin.Length}!");
        if(startPositionX < 0 || startPositionX > originDimensionsX - 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Given startPosition {startPositionX} is outside of the origin dimensions {originDimensionsX}!");
        if(startPositionY < 0 || startPositionY > originDimensionsY - 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Given startPosition {startPositionY} is outside of the origin dimensions {originDimensionsY}!");
        if(targetDimensionsX < 0 || targetDimensionsY < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("TargetDimensions may not be negative!");
        if(startPositionX + targetDimensionsX > originDimensionsX || startPositionY + targetDimensionsY > originDimensionsY) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ($"Given TargetDimensions {targetDimensionsX},{targetDimensionsY} starting at {startPositionX},{startPositionY} does not fit into originDimensions {originDimensionsX},{originDimensionsY}!");

        var output = new int[targetDimensionsX * targetDimensionsY];

        var subIndex = 0;
        for(var y = startPositionY; y < startPositionY + targetDimensionsY; y++)
        {
            // In this case the indices are all referring to bytes instead of array index
            Buffer.BlockCopy(origin, (startPositionX + y * originDimensionsX) * SIZEOF_INT, output, subIndex * SIZEOF_INT, targetDimensionsX * SIZEOF_INT);
            subIndex += targetDimensionsX;
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone -> not tested but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: I think this is probably the best answer so far, thank you very much. I need to check if I can do `BlockCopy` or something similar with `NativeArray`, but the above solution is already quite good and easily parallelizable (by splitting the work into chunks, as it's only dependent on the subIndex).

Comment: Oh for native array you can probably also just use [`NativeArray.Copy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Collections.NativeArray_1.Copy.html) which again is generic and you don't need to know the byte sizes

Comment: Thank you, I totally missed the `Copy` method. I mostly use the `CopyFrom` and `CopyTo` methods and those do not have variants to specify the section you want to copy. This helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that I tried and worked for me. Let me know if it helps:
`

```
        // Size for original array
        int originSizeX = 4;
        int originSizeY = 4;

        // Size for sub array
        int subArrSizeX = 3;
        int subArrSizeY = 3;

        // Starting positions of sub-array in original array
        int startingPosX = 0;
        int StartingPosY = 1;

        // Create original array
        int[] arr = CreateArr(originSizeX, originSizeY);

        // Get sub array
        int[] subArr = GetSubArr(arr, subArrSizeX, subArrSizeY, startingPosX, StartingPosY, originSizeX, originSizeY);


    private static int[] GetSubArr(int[] arr, int subArrSizeX, int subArrSizeY, int startingPosX, int startingPosY, int originArrSizeX, int originArrSizeY)
    {
        int[] subArr = new int[subArrSizeX * subArrSizeY];

        int subArrCurrentIndexX = 0;
        int subArrCurrentIndexY = 0;

        for (int originArrCurrentIndexY = startingPosY; originArrCurrentIndexY < startingPosY + subArrSizeY; originArrCurrentIndexY++)
        {
            for (int originArrCurrentIndexX = startingPosX; originArrCurrentIndexX < startingPosX + subArrSizeX; originArrCurrentIndexX++)
            {
                // Transform indices from 2D to 1D
                int originArrIndex = (originArrCurrentIndexY ) * originArrSizeX + originArrCurrentIndexX ;
                int subArrIndex = (subArrCurrentIndexY ) * subArrSizeX + subArrCurrentIndexX ;

                subArr[subArrIndex] = arr[originArrIndex];

                subArrCurrentIndexX++;

                if (subArrCurrentIndexX == subArrSizeX)
                {
                    subArrCurrentIndexX = 0;
                    subArrCurrentIndexY++;
                }
            }
        }

        return subArr;
    }

    private static int[] CreateArr(int originSizeX, int originSizeY)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[originSizeX * originSizeY];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = i;
        }

        return arr;
    }
```

`

Comment: Thank you, this works, but is unfortunately very slow. I was trying to avoid nested loops for that reason. If there is no other way I will have to deal with it, but I still hope for something more performant. I will try to adjust your algorithm to something that works better in parallel threads with the Unity JobSystem (single loop with consecutive index over the output data), maybe that already provides better performance.

Still much appreciated!